# Help-menu "Tour" link does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed

I don't know if it has to do with the recent meta-move, but if you click on the **Help** menu at the right side of the navigation bar and select a link from it, the link itself refers to (for example):

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help
```

They all redirect properly to their non-meta variant*, for example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/help
```

Except one, the **tour**. If you click on the MetaStackoverflow tour-link, you end up in the StackOverflow help center. There you can obviously click on the "Take the 2-minute tour" link, but it's kind of useless then to have the "Tour" link at the first place.

A really "trivial" bug, but I thought it might be worth mentioning it.

** I don't know if the redirect is meant to be or not.*

Comment: @GrantWinney this is bug in all per-site metas, now that this one is regular per-site meta it's affected as well. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/tour on child metas was supposed to redirect to the parent site's /tour but ... didn't.

This will be fixed in the next build - rev 2014.4.24.2188 here on meta and rev 2014.4.24.1566 elsewhere in the network.